# Using material on pre-Lollipop sdk

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

Since 2 days I try to use the material design in a new app (sdk 20-).

I read some tutorials and with this one [http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html][1] i've this error :

> C:\Users\Maxime\Desktop\MaterialApp\app\src\main\res\values\themes.xml
>   Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Maxime\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio3\sdk\build-tools\21.0.2\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Maxime\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio3\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar -M C:\Users\Maxime\Desktop\MaterialApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Maxime\Desktop\MaterialApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\Maxime\Desktop\MaterialApp\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\Maxime\Desktop\MaterialApp\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Maxime\Desktop\MaterialApp\app\build\intermediates\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.maxime.myapplication -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Maxime\Desktop\MaterialApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       C:\Users\Maxime\Desktop\MaterialApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:2411: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

I add my files that I created to get this :

/res/values/themes.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/yellow</item>

<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>

<!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
     which is used to tint widgets -->
<item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>

<!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

</style>
```

/res/layout/activity_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.maxime.materialapp.HomeActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    layout_height="match_parent"
    layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

/java/package/HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In this last, setSupportActionBar(toolbar) is not recognize.

And my gradle : `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.maxime.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your styles.xml to this `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">` and refer to this tutorial
https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html

Comment: This will not work unless minSdkVersion is set to 21.  To support pre-Lollipop, you need to use some form of Theme.AppCompat

Answer (score 1):

The AppCompat theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, not `android:Theme.AppCompat.Light`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ActionBarActivity` together with `setSupportActionBar` instead of `Activity` if you're going to use the support version of the Toolbar (`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`).

`Activity.setActionBar(android.widget.Toolbar toolbar)` was added in API Level 21 and thus cannot be used with `minSdkVersion 19`

Also, as mentioned by Ian Lake you must use `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, not `android:Theme.AppCompat.Light`